# How do you test a method which doesn’t return any values

Tags: junit, testng

How do you test a method which doesn’t return any values in JUnit/TestNG??

Can you control Junit/TestNG Results from tests?

These are questions I've come across during my interview? How do I answer them??

Comment: If the method doesn't return a value, what you understand saying "works correct"?

Comment: Does the method change the state of the object? If so can you interrogate that object?

Comment: Thank you all. appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe by testing that no Exception is thrown and that the produced side-effect is as expected. It depends on your context though.
As for your question:

> Can you control Junit/TestNG Results from tests?

Maybe using method [fail()](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#fail%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can control method fail - for example exception throwing. For example assert that the code should throw an exception. You have and array and want to check that your array. `JUnit` example:

```
@Test(expected = SomeException.class)
public void testMethod() {
    testMethod(int someValue); // You accept that it should throw an exception
}
```